# Problem compiling .py in .exe because of a problem with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My code works fine when I use <kbd>shift+F10</kbd> in PyCharm. But, when I compiled it using `auto_py_to_exe` or `pyInstaller`, I have the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File main.py, line 62, in <module>
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "babacas.gif": no such file or directory
```

```py
from tkinter import *


def piadinhas():
    nome = inp.get()
    if nome == 'Fabricia' or nome == 'fabricia':
        texto_resultado["text"] = 'E aquela baratinha lá. hein!?'
        imagem_fabricia = Label(janela, image=imgBarata)
        imagem_fabricia.grid(column=0, row=7, pady=2)

    elif nome == 'Roberto' or nome == 'roberto':
        texto_resultado["text"] = 'Para de camperar na caixa da B'
        imagem_odin = Label(janela, image=imgOdin)
        imagem_odin.grid(column=0, row=7, pady=2)

    elif nome == 'Lucas' or nome == 'lucas':
        texto_resultado["text"] = 'Galo Forte Vingador'
        imagem_loko = Label(janela, image=imgLoko)
        imagem_loko.grid(column=0, row=7, pady=2)

    elif nome == 'Leonardo' or nome == 'leonardo':
        texto_resultado["text"] = 'Porque você não ********?'
        imagem_loko = Label(janela, image=imgLeonardo)
        imagem_loko.grid(column=0, row=7, pady=2)

    elif nome == 'Montanha' or nome == 'montanha':
        texto_resultado["text"] = 'Seu nome é montanha, *******?'
        image_montanha = Label(janela, image=imgMontanha)
        image_montanha.grid(column=0, row=7, pady=2)

    elif nome == 'Marcos' or nome == 'marcos' or nome == 'Marcos Cesar':
        texto_resultado["text"] = 'SOCRAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAM, e aquela festinha lá, hein!?'
        image_socram = Label(janela, image=imgSocram)
        image_socram.grid(column=0, row=7, pady=2)

    elif nome == 'Lorenzo' or nome == 'lorenzo' or nome == 'oznerol':
        texto_resultado["text"] = 'Qual o seu dom?'
        image_lorenzo = Label(janela, image=imgLorenzo)
        image_lorenzo.grid(column=0, row=7, pady=2)

    elif nome == 'Camiran' or nome == 'camiran':
        texto_resultado["text"] = 'Quando será o próximo meme de marea pegando fogo?'
        image_camiran = Label(janela, image=imgCamiran)
        image_camiran.grid(column=0, row=7, pady=2)

    elif nome == 'Dennis' or nome == 'dennis':
        texto_resultado['text'] = 'Papai?'
        image_dennis = Label(janela, image=imgDennis)
        image_dennis.grid(column=0, row=7, pady=2)

    else:
        texto_resultado["text"] = 'Você não é um dos Babacas!'
        image_nao = Label(janela, image=imgNao)
        image_nao.grid(column=0, row=7, pady=2)


janela = Tk()
janela.title('Aplicativo de Adjetivos Carinhosos')
janela.geometry('400x500')
janela.config(background='#dde')

This is line 62:  imagemLogo = PhotoImage(file='babacas.gif')
imgBarata = PhotoImage(file='baratinha.gif')
imgOdin = PhotoImage(file='caixa da b.gif')
imgLoko = PhotoImage(file='galo.gif')
imgLeonardo = PhotoImage(file='chuva.gif')
imgMontanha = PhotoImage(file='montanha.gif')
imgSocram = PhotoImage(file='socram.gif')
imgLorenzo = PhotoImage(file='lorenzo.gif')
imgCamiran = PhotoImage(file='camiran.gif')
imgDennis = PhotoImage(file='dennis.gif')
imgNao = PhotoImage(file='não sinto.gif')

logo = Label(janela, image=imagemLogo)
logo.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=75)

texto_apresentacao = Label(janela, text='Eu sei quem você é!', background='#dde')
texto_apresentacao.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=75, pady=10)

texto_orientacao = Label(janela, text="Say Your Name, Don't Lie", background='#dde')
texto_orientacao.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=75, pady=2)

inp = StringVar()
entrada_nome = Entry(janela, textvariable=inp)
entrada_nome.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=75, pady=10)

botao_resultado = Button(janela, width=20, height=2, command=piadinhas)
botao_resultado.grid(column=0, row=4, padx=75, pady=5)

texto_resultado = Label(janela, text="", background='#dde')
texto_resultado.grid(column=0, row=5, pady=15)

janela.mainloop()
```

I can see that the problem is that the `pyinstaller` can't take the images together. But I can't see how to fix it.

Comment: Make sure all the files/resources are together with the .exe file, or the relative path is the same in both, the .py and the .exe file

Comment: The image files can't be found because all their file names are relative to the current working directory — which apparently is different after the script is compiled. It would be best to absolute file path.

Comment: Study official [Run-time Information](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html).

Comment: @martineau For some reason the file .png not going along even giving the command in the auto-py-to-exe. But when I put the file in the folder where the .exe, it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @Dennis: In [Issues When Using auto-py-to-exe](https://nitratine.net/blog/post/issues-when-using-auto-py-to-exe/?utm_source=auto_py_to_exe&utm_medium=readme_link&utm_campaign=auto_py_to_exe_help) see the part that starts with "Next, you need to choose between one-file and one-directory. These are relatively similar but when using one-file with extra files like images or data files you may need to modify your script to account for path changes. The difference between these methods and people ignoring the extra step required generally result in the bulk of complaints I get."

Comment: @martineau I read and did what the article says. It worked out. As I'm in a career transition, and excited, maybe I'm going too fast on what I want to learn. This week I managed to develop a youtube video and audio downloader, with the conversion part to mp3. My wife is a teacher and needs to download several videos to use in the classroom. I focused on that and I got it. I'm talking a lot, but thanks for your help.